# Some values do not store in the database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

i have this code:

```
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If txtCode.Text <> "878" Then
        If ((txtCode.Text <> "") And (txtRefNo.Text <> "") And (txtPayee.Text <> "") And (txtOffice.Text <> "") And (txtAddress.Text <> "") And (txtParticulars.Text <> "") And (txtPPA.Text <> "") And (txtAmount.Text <> "")) Then
            Try
                If IsNumeric(txtAmount.Text) = False Then
                    MsgBox("Amount value should be in correct number format! e.g: 10000.00 or 10,000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
                modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

                modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now)

                Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
                Dim Amount As Double = Double.Parse(txtAmount.Text)

                Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM obligations " & _
                                                         "WHERE ref_no='" & txtRefNo.Text & "'")
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not insert duplicate entries for REFERENCE NO.!", "Form Validations", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Reader.Close()
                    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

                Else
                    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
                    modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

                    modGlobalFunctions.executeNonQuery("INSERT INTO obligations (resp_id, year_id, expenditure_id, ref_no, payee, office, address, particulars, ppa, amount, date_entered, date_edited, signature1, position1, signature2, position2) " & _
                                                       "VALUES ('" & RespCenterId & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & YearId & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & txtExpId.Text & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtRefNo.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtPayee.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtOffice.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtAddress.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtParticulars.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtPPA.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Amount & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Signature1 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Position1 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Signature2 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Position2 & "')")

                    MsgBox("Record has been added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

                    Me.Close()
                    Dispose()
                    frmObligations.MdiParent = frmMain
                    frmObligations.Show()
                    frmObligations.obligationLoadGrid()

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("Please fill up all form fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        End If

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()


    Else

        If ((txtCode.Text <> "") And (txtRefNo.Text <> "") And (txtPayee.Text <> "") And (txtOffice.Text <> "") And (txtAddress.Text <> "") And (txtParticulars.Text <> "")) Then
            Try

                modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
                modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

                modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now)

                Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

                Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM obligations " & _
                                                         "WHERE ref_no='" & txtRefNo.Text & "'")
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not insert duplicate entries for REFERENCE NO.!", "Form Validations", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Reader.Close()
                    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
                Else
                    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
                    modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

                    modGlobalFunctions.executeNonQuery("INSERT INTO obligations (resp_id, year_id, expenditure_id, ref_no, payee, office, address, particulars, date_entered, date_edited, signature1, position1, signature2, position2) " & _
                                                       "VALUES ('" & RespCenterId & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & YearId & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & txtExpId.Text & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtRefNo.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtPayee.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & odGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtOffice.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtAddress.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.addslashes(txtParticulars.Text) & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & modGlobalFunctions.DateTimeNow & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Signature1 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Position1 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Signature2 & "', " & _
                                                               "'" & Position2 & "')")

                    MsgBox("Record has been added! You can now add project title!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    frmProject.MdiParent = frmMain
                    frmProject.Show()
                    frmProject.Label2.Text = txtRefNo.Text
                    Me.Enabled = False

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("Please fill up all form fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        End If

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

    End If

End Sub
```

What do you think is the problem why Signature1, Position1, Signature2 and Position2 doesn't store in the database. It works fine before until i put the if code because of the category... by the way here's the code for signature1, position1, signature2 and position2:

Signature1:

```
     Private Sub cbSignatory1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT person_id FROM persons WHERE person_name='" & cbSignatory1.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                Signature1 = Reader("person_id").ToString()
            End While
        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Signature2:

```
Private Sub cbSignatory2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT person_id FROM persons WHERE person_name='" & cbSignatory2.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                Signature2 = Reader("person_id").ToString()
            End While
        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Position1:

```
Private Sub cbPosition1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT position_id FROM positions WHERE position_name='" & cbPosition1.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                Position1 = Reader("position_id").ToString()
            End While
        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Position2:

```
Private Sub cbPosition2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()

        Reader = modGlobalFunctions.executeQuery("SELECT position_id FROM positions WHERE position_name='" & cbPosition2.Text & "'")

        If Reader.HasRows Then
            While Reader.Read
                Position2 = Reader("position_id").ToString()
            End While
        End If

        Reader.Close()

        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Please *use placeholders/parameters* (look this up, fix the code, and *then* see what problems persist). Not only *might* it "fix" this problem, it will prevent SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: because its just on adding that's why there's no update...

Comment: doesn't you get any error while inserting a record?

Comment: i don't get any error... some values can store in the database except the last four fields... Signature1, Signature2, Position1 & Position2.. :(

Comment: mee too... i see too much code.. hehe... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet `Person_ID` and `position_id` are numeric types in your database. Right? The reason it's not inserting because you wrapped it with single quotes:

```
 "'" & Signature1 & "', " & _        // <== here
 "'" & Position1 & "', " & _
 "'" & Signature2 & "', " & _
 "'" & Position2 & "'
```

Numeric values are not wrap with single quotes. One more thing, I suggest you use  `Command` and `parameters` to avoid SQL Injection.

Example based on your code:

```
Dim sqlStatement AS String = "INSERT INTO obligations (resp_id, year_id, expenditure_id, "
sqlStatement &= "ref_no, payee, office, address, particulars, ppa, amount, date_entered, "
sqlstetement &= "date_edited, signature1, position1, signature2, position2) "
sqlstetement &= "VALUES (@resp_id, @year_id, @expenditure_id, "
sqlStatement &= "@ref_no, @payee, @office, @address, @particulars, @ppa, @amount, @date_entered, "
sqlstetement &= "@date_edited, @signature1, @position1, @signature2, @position2) "

Using xConn AS New MySQLConnection(connStrHere)
    Using xComm AS New MySQLCommand()
        With xComm
            .Connection = xConn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = sqlStatement
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@resp_id", RespCenterId)
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@year_id", YearId)
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@expenditure_id", txtExpId.Text)
            ' continue with other parameters
            ' .....
            ' until you reach the last parameters  '
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@signature1", Signature1)
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@position1", Position1)
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@signature2", Signature2)
            .Parameter.AddWithValue("@position2", Position2)
        End With
        Try
            xConn.Open()
            xComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record has been added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex AS MySQLException
            MsgBox(e.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Finally
            xConn.Open()
        End try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: +1 For showing the use of parameters. *However*, it should be *okay* if numbers are wrapped in (string) single quotes because of implicit coercions ..